# Find and extract text in email with Python

Tags: python, pywin32

My goal is to get a random login code from an email.

I have the email but I don't know how to extract the login code from the email.

The login code is the only text in bold within the email and would be made up of random numbers and letters.

How do I find the code in the email to use elsewhere in my script?

This is the code to get the email.

```
   import win32com.client
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    
    def get_email_code():
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')
        mapi = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        inbox = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(6)
        emails = inbox.Items
        receive_time = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=1)
        receive_time = received_dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')
        emails = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + received_dt + "'")
        emails = messages.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'test@test.com'")
        emails = messages.Restrict("[Subject] = 'test'")
        codeEmail = emails[0]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to analyse the body of the email. There are two option: If you can find the code via Regex, just take the body `codeEmail.body` as text. If that is not enough, you can analyse `codeEmail.HTMLBody` using for example BeautifulSoup and search for the <b>-tag.

Comment: What if body is ```quoted printable``` or ```base64```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used the HTMLBody and figured out how to use regex, got the code now!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments I got the answer I needed!

I used the `.HTMLBody` with my my email and figured out how to use regex to find the HTML code that held the code.

```
codeEmail = codeEmail.HTMLBody

pattern = r'.*?\<strong style="font-size:200%">(.*)<.*'
match = re.search(pattern,codeEmail)
print(match.group(1))
```

Thanks all for your help!